# Select All option in Dynamic Parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

Trying to include an "[ALL]" option to my list of dynamic field values in the dynamic parameter. I read that I should try using database commands to do this. I implemented the command as I saw on the internet:

select SEA_EPPS_MAIN. "Org_unit"
FROM EMSDBA.SEA_EPPS_MAIN
union
select '[ALL]'
from EMSDBA.SEA_EPPS_MAIN

However, when I run this (I have three commands since I want [ALL] to be included on the three parameters the report uses), I get massively duplicated records.

I know something is off with my SQL command, but I can't find a clear example of what it needs to be to behave properly.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you need this parameter to allow multiples?

Comment: If it's not too cumbersome to include multiples, it would be a nice option. However, all that's required is to be able to select all from any or all of the three parameters.

Comment: Can you show your other two SQL command tables?

Comment: Of course:'select SEA_EPPS_MAIN. "Project Number"
FROM EMSDBA.SEA_EPPS_MAIN
union
select '[ALL]'
from EMSDBA.SEA_EPPS_MAIN'

Comment: And: select SEA_EPPS_MAIN. "Engineer"
FROM EMSDBA.SEA_EPPS_MAIN
union
select '[ALL]'
from EMSDBA.SEA_EPPS_MAIN

Comment: Do you have other tables in your report?

Comment: There are two subreports that each call on their own tables, but the only one in the main report is "SEA_EPPS_MAIN"

Comment: Dont use union use right outer join instead and try